# EntityDataSource: TotalRowCount returns -1. What's that?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entitydatasource

I have an EntityDataSource with `OnSelected` event (fired after finished query). The event handler has event args of type `EntityDataSourceSelectedEventArgs e`. Query runs fine without error and the IEnumerable `e.Results` contains 1 object (I can run through a non-empty foreach-loop) but `e.TotalRowCount` returns `-1`.

Does somebody have an idea what this means and what information `TotalRowCount` actually expresses? How can I determine the number of selected objects if not by using `TotalRowCount`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.selected(VS.100).aspx:

```
    The TotalRowCount property of the EntityDataSourceSelectedEventArgs 
object shows the total number of objects in all pages, regardless of the 
values passed by the data-bound control for paging. 

    TotalRowCount is only retrieved if the data-bound 
control needs it, such as if paging is enabled.
```

Is your data-bound control using paging?

Comment: No, it doesn't use paging. OK, thanks, that explains why TotalRowCount is useless without paging. But how can I determine the number of objects then?

Comment: Since e.Results is an IEnumerable, how about e.Results.Count() ?

Comment: e.Results is an `System.Collections.IEnumerable` which does not seem to have a `Count()` method or property - in contrast to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Try importing the Linq namespace and using it's extension method.

Comment: System.Linq and System.Data.Linq was already imported but it doesn't help. The extension method seems only to be available for the generic version of IEnumerable but not for the non-generic version. After looking at various other discussions here about IEnumerable I think the only way is really to iterate through IEnumerable and to count the objects.

Comment: This post may be of some help if you want to write your own extension method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155619/ienumberable-to-something-that-i-can-get-a-count-from